# Set folder to open during startup

Tags: boot, ubuntu-15.04

In `Ubuntu 15.04` how can I have a folder open during login?  I know how to launch an application, but what about a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch the application `nautilus` with the command-line arguments being `/path/to/folder`. The full command is: `nautilus /path/to/folder`.

1. Open the dash and search for: startup
2. Click `Startup Applications`
3. Click `Add`
4. Options

   - Name: Open Folder (or anything else)
   - Command: `nautilus /path/to/folder`
5. Press `Add`
6. Reboot the machine